# Looking for a faceted search, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I am looking for a JavaScript library which enables the development of a faceted search. That is, I have >600 data sets the user can search for, and I'd like to offer a couple of "groupings", such as "Theme", "Region", "Resolution" so that the user can easily boil the list down to just a few data sets.

Not sure if this must use AJAX; but I guess it should.

I've found [filters.js](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2011/09/28/filter-js-client-side-search-filtering-using-json-and-jquery/) so far, and [this one](http://eikes.github.com/facetedsearch/). But that's about it. There is quite a bit out there for Drupal, and for Solr. But that's not what I am working on.

If you have any recommendations for libs which would be easily adaptable in a "normal" HTML/JavaScript environment, I would very much appreciate any hints.

Comment: I've found another one quite nice, but it just wouldn't work with 600 variables to be displayed "hidden" on the webpage: http://webegg.co.uk/jquery-multiple-filter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally went with [this one](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/autosuggestion-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html).

It's easily adoptable, so that I have now multiple checkboxes which allow for deeper drilling into the available data sets.

Comment: for anyone who looks at this question in the future, I ended up writing my own jQuery plugin to help with faceted search: https://github.com/srchulo/jQuery-Facets/

Comment: @srchulo Congratulations, your plugin is now the first Google hit. ;)

Comment: @abaumg ha! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

How about the [VisualSearch](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/) library?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer i.e., the link you have shared.

Comment: The demo on the linked page does not get submitted; this one ( https://www.documentcloud.org/public/search/) operates on a dataset. Click in, a choice of categories/facets appears, choose one, a list of items appear. To type free text, start typing "text". There is quite an extensive help in the thumbnail on the top of the page. Further you can e explore the data sent to the server with firebug. (It worked better with the dev inspection tool in Chrome as Firebug kept closing after every request.)

Comment: Heavily dependant on Backbone and underscore. If your project already has lodash causes conflict as it uses _.any() function internally not supported by lodash